# Content not updating(Javascript with HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner to javascript. I am currently learning it.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Using Javascript</title>
        <meta http-equiv="author" content="@infinity">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Elderflower</h1>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
        <div id="content">
            <h2>Custom Signage</h2>
            <div id="cost">Cost: $5 per tile</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var number;
var costOne;
var totalCost;

number=5;
costOne=2;
totalCost=number*costOne;

var el=document.getElementById('cost');
el.textContent=totalCost;
```

Now I think that this should work, but its not working. The text of the `<div id="cost">` remains same.

Please help.

Comment: What is that? Please?

Comment: How is the JavacScript included in the page?

Comment: @Siddhant Move the script to the end of body

Comment: @Tushar, that works... thnx

Comment: Btw @Tushar, what is innerText and innerHTML?

Comment: @Siddhant Check [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are trying to update the DOM even before it is loaded - you can make sure the javascript is executed after the DOM is loaded by keeping JS at the end of the body tag like below -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Using Javascript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Elderflower</h1>
        <div id="content">
            <h2>Custom Signage</h2>
            <div id="cost">Cost: $5 per tile</div>
        </div>
        <script>
                var number;
                var costOne;
                var totalCost;

                 number=5;
                 costOne=2;
                 totalCost=number*costOne;

                var el=document.getElementById('cost');
                el.textContent=totalCost;
        </scirpt>
    </body>
</html>
```

Start reading from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload) about **Window load vs DOM load** events